# Dynamically setting styleUrls for component based on the current window location

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm trying to set an angular component `styleUrls` value based on a condition `window.location.href.includes('en')`

`home-page.component.ts`:

```
let condition = window.location.href.includes('en');

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home-page',
    templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: [condition ? './home-page.component.scss' : './home-page.component-rtl.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {
    //....
}
```

But I'm getting an error `error NG1010: styleUrls must be an array of strings`.

I tried already to change the first line to another condition, ie: `let condition = 1 + 1 == 2;`, and the error didn't show. It only shows when I use `window.SOMETHING` inside the condition.

As I investigate more, the error appears because `window` is undefined before the component loads.

How can I set the value `styleUrls` based on a condition depending on `window.location.href` value?
How can I access `window` before the component is loaded?

Comment: Is this happening during runtime?

Comment: That won't work, as it'll be resolved at build time. You need to find another way to change the style.

Comment: @VRoxa Yes, it happens during runtime.